# How can I write files in /opt?

Tags: installation

while trying to install XAMP from a tar file using the command: `tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz -C /opt`, I get the following message:  `Cannot mkdir: Permission denied`

Where and how do I set permissions?

Answer (score 8):

/opt is owned by root(admin user), you would need to change the owner to you, or just use the sudo command.

to change ownership use chown

```
sudo chown username:username /opt
```

but it would probally be esier for you to use the command with sudo precceed to it

```
sudo tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.7.tar.gz -C /opt
```

nautilus allows to change ownership as well, but youll need to use nautilus as root

```
gksudo nautilus /
```

then right click on opt go to properties, then go to the permissions tab, and change as neccessary

changing file permsioons can also be done with chmod

for any more information with these commands, try using the man manual pages
by using `man` followed by the command, you can also use the info command  as well.