# Why compressed directories cannot be extracted in /opt?

Tags: tar, compression, gzip

I am not able to uncompress a file with .tar.gz extension

Did
`sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/file.tar.gz /opt/` but no success.
it says:

```
tar: /opt: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: I had a hard time on this one, go to:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/148245/how-can-i-write-files-in-opt

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can specify in which directory you want the files extracted using the `-C` option. Change your command to:

```
sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/file.tar.gz -C /opt/
```

Answer (score 7):

Your are telling `tar` to look for `/opt/` inside the tar file and to extract only that and since it is not in that tar file it throws an error. Do:

```
cd /opt
sudo cp  ~/Downloads/file.tar.gz .
sudo tar -xvzf file.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

use `--directory` before the directory path at which you would like to extract:

```
sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/file.tar.gz --directory /opt/
```